# ASP.NET WebPages Custom Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-webpages, razor-3

I've been thinking if it's possible to create your own "classes", for example if I wanted to create a "Division" system under my Users table, would I be able to make a "class" I can use in my cshtml files which checks whether a certain user is a member of the division or not, without having to do the same query every time it needs to check?

For example for something like:

```
if (!Divisions.IsUserInDivision("division"))
{
    Response.Redirect("~/");
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really struggling to understand. Divistions is some sort of permissions checked yeah? I'm not sure what your question is...

Comment: For example; Normally you have Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"), which checks if a user is in the "Admin" role. I want to make a system with "Divisions", where it can check if a user is in a specific division or not. So I'm wondering whether I can create something called Divisions.IsUserInDivision("division") myself, or if that's not possible. Thank you

Comment: it's certainly possible. In general "Is this possible" questions are a bad fit for SO, this site is much better for "This is what I've done and this is what I'm having trouble with" type questions. I would suggest you write some code, see how far you get and come back with specific questions about code you've written.

Comment: Why can't you use roles for this?

Comment: @Liath I've seen plenty of "this is what I've done and this is what I'm having trouble with" questions closed on this site due to them being too localised or some such nonsense.

Comment: @MikeBrind sure - depends on the quality of the question obviously

Comment: So are you trying to check if a user can access a set of pages?

Comment: @Liath - The thing is, I didn't have ANY code to show. I haven't tried anything, I did create a Class file, but that's how far I got. I tried Googling around but couldn't find anything on it, I don't know if my search strings weren't formulated right, but the fact is I didn't find anything, which is why I wanted to ask some more experienced developers here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @MVCDS - Sort of, it was more of a general question, it's a pain doing the same queries over and over again, with classes like this I can do it more easily and without the same queries over and over.

Comment: @Mikkel You won't get judged for the "quality" of your question at http://forums.asp.net.

Comment: @MikeBrind - Thank you, I think I will create an account on there right away.

Comment: Have you considered to make those divisions as role (once you already know how to use it, it seems) - "admDivision", "itDivision", "mktDivision" and so on?

Comment: @MVCDS - I considered that yes, and that might also be the approach I'm going to use. I've just been wanting to know how to make classes for a while, as I plan on using it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly add your own classes to a Razor Web Pages site. You must create an App_Code folder if you don't already have one and place them there.

```
public class Divisions
{

    public static bool IsUserInDivision(string division){
        // add your checking code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew this was about the App_Code folder and class files, I've been Googling around for an answer to this but haven't been able to find any that solved my specific question.